# Run useEffect only once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm making a request with NextJS, Typescript and I want to clean it up, I don't have a database every month. Or a problem I encountered is making only a single request, not a single request for each useEffect render.

**Main code**

```
  const { lastDayMonth, url, today } = constants
  const [history, setHistory] = useState<Data>()
  const [lastDay, setLastDay] = useState<string>(lastDayMonth)
  const [messageClearDatabase, setMessageCleanDatabase] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getCleanDatabase(){
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(`${url}/destroy`)
        if(response.status === 200) setMessageCleanDatabase('Banco limpo com sucesso!')
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('Erro ao limpar banco de dados')
      }
    }
    if(today === lastDay) getCleanDatabase()

  }, [])
```

**Constants Code**

```
import moment from 'moment'
moment.locale('pt-br')

export default {
  url: 'http://localhost:8005',
  lastDayMonth: moment().endOf('month').format('DD'),
  today: moment().format('DD')
}
```

the if above says that if today hits the last day of the month, it will clean the bank. However, at each rendering of the component my database would be deleted as it would always fall into that if. How can I perform this function ONLY once a day?

Comment: probably best to store something server-side that shows that the database has been cleared for that month.  Client-side had no real solid solution for this.  All client-side storage can be easily removed.

Comment: This implementation seems flawed. What if no one visits your React site on the last day of the month? Then the database cleanup logic will never run for that month. Is that acceptable? This logic belongs on the back-end.

Comment: To expand on what @andymccullough said, the idea of being able to consistently run a function once a *day* on the client side seems... unlikely? The user would have to have an active tab displaying your page at all times (as some browsers throttle intervals in background tabs).

Comment: Create a bash script on the server side and set the cron tab to execute this script once a month.